# mongodb c++ replica set getScopedDbConnection crash

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongodb-c

I'm having troubles connecting to replica set from my c++ application.
Everything is fine if connecting to single mongo instance. But the application crashes if trying to connect to replica set.
"Crashes" means that the process just disappears after entering into ScopedDbConnection::getScopedDbConnection.

Below is my code. It was compiled on EC2 instance running Amazon linux with g++ compiler.
I come from Windows world and don't know how to extract more information regarding the crash (for example, stack).

```
void run()
{
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Before connection");

    // scoped_ptr<ScopedDbConnection> conn( ScopedDbConnection::getScopedDbConnection("54.83.49.200")); // works just fine

    // next line causes a crash
    scoped_ptr<ScopedDbConnection> conn( ScopedDbConnection::getScopedDbConnection("myreplset/54.83.49.200,54.83.53.241,54.83.52.158"));

    DBClientBase * client = conn->get();

    syslog(LOG_INFO, "After connection"); // newer happens if connecting to replica set 

    do_something(client);

    conn->done();

}
```

MongoDB servers installed on Amazon EC2 from pre-configured images (AMI) provided by 10gen and have version 2.4.9
The only change was setting up the replica set.

C++ driver compiled from MongoDB source version 2.4.9. Boost version is 1.53.

Replica set configuration:

```
myreplset:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "myreplset",
        "date" : ISODate("2014-03-26T22:15:11Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "54.83.49.200:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 595,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1395872014, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-03-26T22:13:34Z"),
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "54.83.53.241:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 95,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1395872014, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-03-26T22:13:34Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-03-26T22:15:10Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-03-26T22:15:11Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 1,
                        "syncingTo" : "54.83.49.200:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "54.83.52.158:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 7,
                        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                        "uptime" : 93,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-03-26T22:15:10Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-03-26T22:15:10Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 1
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Firewall seems to be tuned correctly.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the port info and try:

```
 scoped_ptr<ScopedDbConnection> conn( ScopedDbConnection::getScopedDbConnection("myreplset/54.83.49.200:27017,54.83.53.241:27017,54.83.52.158:27017"));
```

Refer client/dbclientinterface.h:
ConnectionString handles parsing different ways to connect to mongo and determining method
foo/server:port,server:port   SET